# How do I configure Ubuntu to run a python (backup) script every night at midnight?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, services, python

New to Ubuntu (and Linux in general) and have whipped up a quick python script to backup my files and do some other housekeeping.  I don't see any service scheduling tools and was wondering what the best way to do this is.

Comment: There's a ton of backup tools, you don't have to write your own. Check out **duplicity** for example.

Comment: Here is a good reference: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `cron`.

1. Run `crontab -e`
2. Add this line:

   ```
   0 0 * * * ~/myscript.py
   ```

   Or simpler:

   ```
   @daily ~/myscript.py
   ```
3. Exit the editor.

See [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crontab) for an explanation of crontab format.

---

I don't know which editor Ubuntu picks by default, but it's likely to be a terminal-based one. If it's `nano`, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> to exit. For `vim`, <kbd>Esc</kbd>, then `:wq` <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

To get the GNOME Editor, use `export EDITOR=gedit` before running `crontab.`

Answer (score 0):

install webmin first. it gives you an easy way to setup scheduled (cron) jobs. just point and click in a GUI.